# BeautifulSoup removes trailing whitespace?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Apparently using Soup.text removes trailing whitespace for some reason.  For example:

```
In [1]: from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup

In [2]: print Soup('<a href=''>a  </a>').text+ 'a'
aa
```

Is this intended behaviour and is there any way to stop it happening?

Edit: the desired output is

```
a  a
```

Comment: This has been reported as a bug since May: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/788986

Comment: Yep, you are right - I'm using an altered version of BeautifulSoup now.  Although a workaround might be helpful as well since it doesn't look like anyone's planning on fixing the bug, and maybe it's desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it comes from the fact that trailing whitespaces are eliminated in HTML

Comment: I had the same thought, although white space is eliminated entirely in places where it should be merely collapsed to a single space.